# Asymmetric nearest-neighbour in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, nearest-neighbor, asymmetric

From a sorted map, I want to retrieve a subset of *n* entries, starting *m* entries before a specified value *v*. For example, for the key set *k* = {0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0}, a query with *n*=5, *m*=2, *v*=0.5, would return {0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9}. Is there an implementation of a data structure in Java supporting such a query, without having to iterate over the whole (big) set?

What do I need this for? Interpolation. I want to interpolate at *v* based on the values in the map. However, I have many *v*. They are sorted, and have a spacing between them much smaller than the ones in *k*. So, I take a range of entries from the map, do some expensive preparatory calculations with them (for example calculating coefficients of a polynom), and can then quickly interpolate another value in that range (by evaluating the polynom with that value).

But why do I need the *m* entries before *v*? The values in *k* are usually equally spaced, and in order to avoid the Runge phenomenon of high oscillations at the ends of the interpolation interval, I simply cut them off, which means I need some nodes before the actual valid interval of the interpolation.

Does that make sense? What’s your suggestion?

(It would be fun if a method like java.util.TreeMap.ceilingEntry() would return an iterator, with which I could step back twice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `headMap()` *and* `tailMap()` is probably the most straightforward solution. If one fears the overhead of making the same search twice, using a list instead of a map is probably the solution. I extended Petar’s suggestion. It can now handle key-value pairs, represented by the small subclass `Pair`:

```
public class DataSet {

  // Usage example
  public static void main (String [] args) {

    DataSet nn = new DataSet ();
    nn.add(0.2,1);
    nn.add(0.3,2);
    nn.add(0.4,3);
    nn.add(0.6,4);
    nn.add(0.8,5);
    nn.add(0.9,6);
    nn.add(1.0,7);

    int n = 5;
    int m = 2;
    double v = 0.5;

    ListIterator <Pair> it = nn.iterator(v);
    for (int i=0; i<m; ++i)
      it.previous();      
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
      System.out.append(it.next()+"\n");
  }

  // Implementation
  TreeSet <Pair> set = new TreeSet <Pair> (new PairComparator());
  ArrayList <Pair> list = new ArrayList <Pair> ();
  boolean listUpToDate = false;

  // Add data
  boolean add (double x, double y) {
    listUpToDate = false;
    return set.add(new Pair(x,y));
  }

  // Get iterator at specified position
  ListIterator <Pair> iterator (double v) {
    if (!listUpToDate) {
      list = new ArrayList (set);
      listUpToDate = true;
    }
    int pos = Collections.binarySearch(list,v);
    if (pos < 0)
      pos = -pos - 1;
    return list.listIterator(pos);
  }

  // Helper class
  static class Pair implements Comparable <Double> {
    double x, y;
    Pair (double x, double y) {
      this.x = x; this.y = y;
    }
    public int compareTo (Double d) {
      return Double.valueOf(x).compareTo(d);
    }
    public String toString () {
        return String.format("[%.1f,%.1f]",x,y);
    }
  }

  // Used for sorting
  class PairComparator implements Comparator <Pair> {
    public int compare (Pair n0, Pair n1) {
      return Double.valueOf(n0.x).compareTo(Double.valueOf(n1.x));
    }
  }

}
```

Of course, one could also just use the list, and make sure it is sorted before calling `binarySearch()`. But the `TreeSet` has also the advantage, besides the ordering, that it prevents duplicate keys.

Answer (score 1):

This is much simpler than that:

1. Use binary search to get the position at which v would be inserted in the list so that it will stay sorted.
2. Move m positions to the left
3. Take the first n elements to the right.

   ```
   double[] k = new double[] {0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0};
   int n=5;
   int m=2;
   double v=0.5;

   int pos = Arrays.binarySearch(k, v);
   if (pos < 0)
       pos = -pos - 1;

   while(pos > 0 && k[pos-1]==v)
       --pos;

   pos = Math.max(pos-m, 0);

   double[] result = Arrays.copyOfRange(k, pos, Math.min(pos+n, k.length));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can place the entries in a sorted array and use a Arrays.binarySearch().

However if you must have a NavigableMap like TreeMap, you need to do two lookups to get the headMap() and tailMap() and iterate over those.